# /proc/sys vs /sys/modules/mod/parameter

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I've been wondering for last few days how exactly does it work.
We can set kernel runtimes parameters using sysctl or echo boolen 1> /proc/sys/module/exactParameter
But in /sys/modules/module/parameters/parameter we can also set values.

Are parameters for modules in /proc/sys/ related only to hard complied into kernel? or there could be parameters for Loadable Kernel Modules also?

LKM after being loaded into running Kernel reveal their parameters in /sys/modules/module/paraeter/params. Does it mean, that there aren't parameters for modules compiled into Kernel?

What is difference between both directories.

according to kernel-parameters.txt:

> Module parameters for modules that are built into the kernel image
>   are specified on **the kernel command line** with the module name plus
>   '.' plus parameter name, with '=' and value if appropriate, such as:

```
    usbcore.blinkenlights=1
```

What does mean kernel command line? Is it related to bootloader (GRUB | LILO) ?

Comment: When a module is loaded it can be given arguments.  You can pass those args via insmod.  When arguments are passed via grub/lilo upon boot-up, the module is specified by preceding the parameter with a '.'.  sysfs and procfs are different.  Each have their own handlers and registration mechanisms.  sysfs is more structured.

Comment: Thanks for explaining last question.

Comment: The directory */proc/sys* is typically used from kernel parameters and should be **not** be used by *modules*.  It is *deprecated* and left for backwards compatibility.  The *proc* file system is meant for *processes*. The *sysfs* is meant for system configuration.  You can add a file/parameter to each, but the **MODULE** macros will only put them in the *sysfs* automatically (or via the macro).